# Deploying rails application to heroku, leaflet map not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, leaflet

I have a leaflet map working perfectly well on localhost, but when pushed up to heroku it doesn't show up on the page. `heroku logs` showed the error `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/leaflet_map.js"):`
I ran `rake assets:precompile`. Now, instead I'm getting error messages like `(No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/l.geosearch.provider.openstreetmap.js"):`.
I really don't known what the hell I'm doing. Can someone please point me in the right direction?
As far as I can tell from searching the relevant pieces of code are:

production.rb:

```
config.serve_static_files = false
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require underscore
//= require_tree .
```

show.html.erb:

```
<div id="map-leaflet"></div>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/easy-button" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/leaflet_map" %>
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.0'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.23.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.3.5.1'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem 'rails-html-sanitizer',    '1.0.1'
gem 'arel'
gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-doc'
gem 'underscore-rails'
gem 'gon'
gem 'autosize',                '~> 1.1.18.4'
gem 'figaro'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
  gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.4.0', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'unicorn',        '4.8.3'
end
```

Comment: try RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add public/assets
git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"

Comment: Tried it but keep getting the error message `Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key` and I can't fix it.

Comment: Can you show your entire gem file? Sounds like it wants to push assets to S3 maybe.

Comment: Edited - added the whole gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

***What fixed my issue was switching from HTTPS > HTTP***

I ran into a similar scenario. On localhost Leaflet javascript runs and renders the map just as expected. I then freeze everything, push to Heroku, click the "Open App" and bam, no map renders. The `<div id="map"></div>` tag is empty. (*I have no error message in the Heroku console however.*)

[Heroku Launching HTTPS and no Leaflet Map Renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfRfq.png)

By default Heroku wants to load "HTTPS". Herein lies the problem. Your localhost is probably not using an SSL layer (HTTPS) so everything works as expected, the catch is that not all the mapping APIs support an SSL layer (HTTPS.) OpenStreetMap for example doesn't support it natively as of API v0.6.

[Manually Changing the URI From HTTPS to HTTP and the Leaflet Map Renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inmpx.png)

So just changing the URI from https:// to http:// allowed my map being pulled from OpenStreetMap.org to render properly. I hope this helps your situation!?